# Event-Based Networking

Tags: java, sockets

I have setup a simple server and client, where the server waits for the client to send something and then sends a response. But the downside is that both have to listen for the socket to receive something. What if I wanted it to be more flexible in the communication? I was thinking something event-based, so every time the socket received something it'd call a method to handle it, instead of pausing the program to wait for socket.nextLine().

Here's what my server code looks like:

```
try{
    ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    s = ss.accept();

    in = new Scanner(s.getInputStream());
    out = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
    while(!s.isClosed()){
        String input = in.nextLine();
        handleInput(input);
    }
} catch (Exception e){}
```

And in the handleInput() I send a response to the client.

Comment: You could take a look at SocketChannel (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html). I'm not sure if it does exactly what you want. But they are very efficient.

Comment: You're doing even-driven networking right now -- you're waiting for input before doing anything. I would recommend you create a whole separate class (thread it) for handling connections. Each time you accept a connection, pass it to that class and start up a thread so your server can keep listening.

Comment: This is a hard topic to put in a post, as there are so many things you could do architecturally.  Here's a tutorial on using selectors, in that you can check to see which sockets are ready to be read/written.  http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/selectors.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be event based with the client doing something when the server sends a packet, then multithread.

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        someMethod(in.nextLine());
    }
});
t.start();
```

You'd have to make `in` a field in the enclosing class.

This would cause your program to execute, and when a it receives a packet it would call `someMethod()`.

Of course, this opens up a multitude of problems associated with multithreading, but it's really the only way to do what you want to.